# Class cannot be resolved to a type?

Tags: java

Do i need to define the SpaService class differently, or import it somehow? I'm new to java and have been stuck on this for a while. This code is almost an exact copy of code from my textbook so I'm really confused as to why its not compiling.

```
public class SpaService 
{
    private String serviceDescription;
    private double price;
    public void setServiceDescription(String service)
    {
        serviceDescription = service;
    }
    public void setPrice(double pr)
    {
        price = pr;
    }
    public String getServiceDescription()
    {
        return serviceDescription;
    }
        public double getPrice()
    {
            return price;
    }
}
```

in a seperate file:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateSpaServices 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String service;
        double price;
        SpaService firstService = new SpaService();
        SpaService secondService = new SpaService();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter service >> ");
        service = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter price >> ");
        price = keyboard.nextDouble();
        firstService.setServiceDescription(service);
        firstService.setPrice(price);
        keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter service >> ");
        service = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter price >> ");
        price = keyboard.nextDouble();
        secondService.setServiceDescription(service);
        secondService.setPrice(price);
        System.out.println("First service details:");
        System.out.println(firstService.getServiceDescription() +
        " $" + firstService.getPrice());
        System.out.println("Second service details:");
        System.out.println(secondService.getServiceDescription() +
        " $" + secondService.getPrice());
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    SpaService cannot be resolved to a type
    SpaService cannot be resolved to a type
    SpaService cannot be resolved to a type
    SpaService cannot be resolved to a type

    at CreateSpaServices.main(CreateSpaServices.java:9)
```

EDIT::
I was able to get it to run properly by putting the SpeService class in a seperate package within the same src as CreateSpaServices class (in the default package) and importing the class from said package. Do i need to configure a path in my IDE (I'm using Eclipse)?If so how should i go about that so that i can access classes from completely separate projects in the future?

Comment: press ctrl+shift+o on main class and save.

Answer (score 0):

Compilation error means you didn’t fix an error beforehand. Check if anything has a red line under it in your IDE in your SpaService class.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you forgot putting the package declaration. It seems your program does not correctly import SpaService class. Are they in the same src hierarchy?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in Eclipse and it's working fine.Are you sure the name of files is the same with the classes?Try to press right click on one class and run as Java Application(if you use Eclipse,i think you can do this in other IDEs).You can try to restart your IDE too.Try to save your code too.